# Saving an array of objects to db Nodejs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, save, arrayobject

I'm fairly new to Nodejs and MongoDB.

So I've built a schema in Nodejs looking like this (*shown below*) - **Data Schema**

```
// create Data Schema
const dataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    allItems: {
        // store all expenses here
        exp: [{
            description: { type: String, require: true, min: 2, max: 50 },
            value: { type: Number, require: true },
            percentage: { type: Number, require: true }
        }],
        // store all incomes here
        inc: [{
            description: { type: String, require: true, min: 2, max: 50 },
            value: { type: Number, require: true }
        }]
    },
    // store total incomes & expenses
    totals: {
        // sum of total expenses, init = 0
        exp: { type: Number, require: true, default: 0},
        // sum of total incomes, init = 0
        inc: { type: Number, require: true, default: 0}
    },
    // store total budgets, init = 0
    budget: { type: Number, require: true, default: 0 },
    // store percentage of total budget
    // init -1 = something is not in existance yet
    percentage: { type: Number, require: true, default: -1 } 
})
```

and have a ***post router*** to *save* new data to db (*as shown below*)

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    // hold exp & inc array length
    expLength = req.body.allItems.exp.length
    incLength = req.body.allItems.inc.length

    // do something to hold allItems exp & inc data first
    // do some code here?

    // create new data
    const data = new Data({
        allItems: {
            exp: [
                {
                    description: req.body.allItems.exp,
                    value: req.body.allItems.exp,
                    percentage: req.body.allItems.exp
                }
            ],
            inc: [
                {
                    description: req.body.allItems.inc,
                    value: req.body.allItems.inc
                }
            ]
        },
        totals: {
            exp: req.body.totals.exp,
            inc: req.body.totals.inc
        },
        budget: req.body.budget,
        percentage: req.body.percentage
    })

    try {
        const saveData = await data.save()
        res.json(saveData)
    } catch(err) {
        res.json({
            message: err
        })
    }
})
```

So I'm using **Postman** to help me learn about nodejs and mongodb.

In postman, I have this data (*as shown below*) ready to be executed. Where, I've **2 objects in array exp** under **allItems**.

```
{
    "allItems": {
        "exp": [
            // first object
            {
                "description": "Rent",
                "value": 500,
                "percentage": 50
            },
            // second object
            {
                "description": "Loan",
                "value": 250,
                "percentage": 25
            }
        ],
        "inc": [
            {
                "description": "Web",
                "value": 1000
            }
        ]
    },
    "totals": {
        "exp": 750,
        "inc": 1000
    },
    "budget": 250,
    "percentage": 75
}
```

But unfortunately it only able to save **1 object, which is the first one since I set the array to be '0' in post router** (*as shown below*).

```
{
    "totals": {
        "exp": 750,
        "inc": 1000
    },
    "budget": 250,
    "percentage": 75,
    "_id": "5e6139b3111a7b593ce296cd",
    "allItems": {
        "exp": [
            // only save the first object
            {
                "_id": "5e6139b3111a7b593ce296ce",
                "description": "Rent",
                "value": 500,
                "percentage": 50
            }
        ],
        "inc": [
            {
                "_id": "5e6139b3111a7b593ce296cf",
                "description": "Web",
                "value": 1000
            }
        ]
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

I think I should do a **for loop** or something to **store** the array of **inc & exp** data first. But I just don't know how.

I've been searching it through google. But got no luck yet. Anyway, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Btw, it gave me this error (*as shown below*) -

```
"_message": "Data validation failed",
"message": "Data validation failed: allItems.exp.0.description: Cast to String failed for value \"[\n  { description: 'Rent', value: 500, percentage: 50 },\n  { description: 'Loan', value: 250, percentage: 25 }\n]\" at path \"description\", allItems.exp.0.value: Cast to Number failed for value \"[\n  { description: 'Rent', value: 500, percentage: 50 },\n  { description: 'Loan', value: 250, percentage: 25 }\n]\" at path \"value\", allItems.exp.0.percentage: Cast to Number failed for value \"[\n  { description: 'Rent', value: 500, percentage: 50 },\n  { description: 'Loan', value: 250, percentage: 25 }\n]\" at path \"percentage\", allItems.inc.0.description: Cast to String failed for value \"[ { description: 'Web', value: 1000 } ]\" at path \"description\", allItems.inc.0.value: Cast to Number failed for value \"[ { description: 'Web', value: 1000 } ]\" at path \"value\"",
"name": "ValidationError"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a forEach loop on **req.body.allItems.exp** and prepare the **expArr** array to be saved in **exp**:

```
var expArr = [];
req.body.allItems.exp.forEach(function(eachObj){
   var obj = {
      "description": eachObj.description,
      "value": eachObj.value,
      "percentage": eachObj.percentage
   }
   expArr.push(obj);
});
```

Although, by looking at your code, seems like there is no need for any loop, you can just save the **exp** data directly like this:

```
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {

// hold exp & inc array length
expLength = req.body.allItems.exp.length
incLength = req.body.allItems.inc.length

// do something to hold allItems exp & inc data first
// do some code here?

// create new data
const data = new Data({
    allItems: {
        exp: req.body.allItems.exp,
        inc: req.body.allItems.inc
    },
    totals: {
        exp: req.body.totals.exp,
        inc: req.body.totals.inc
    },
    budget: req.body.budget,
    percentage: req.body.percentage
})

try {
    const saveData = await data.save()
    res.json(saveData)
} catch(err) {
    res.json({
        message: err
    })
 }
})
```

Comment: It gave errors of `message: Data validation failed`. I've updated my question above. Please have a look at it. How can I ignore the validation?

Comment: @lala Kindly read my answer carefully. I am assigning "req.body.allItems.exp" directly to "exp" in "allItems". You are assigning "req.body.allItems.exp" to "description", "value" and "percentage". Please replace your "const data" part code with my "const data" part. It will work.

Comment: Oh sorry! My bad. Anyway, is there any particular reasons why I don't have to specify the `key&value` pairs of data inside `exp & inc`. I don't know it can work like that. Not until you showed it to me.

Comment: It depends on how the values are in "req.body", if it is in the same format as schema, you don't need to process them again before adding it to DB.

Comment: Oh nice to know! Anyway, thanks for the help! Appreciated it!